# Does there exist a holomorphic function $\varphi(z)$ such that $\varphi^2(z) = \psi(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\psi(z) \neq 0$ is a holomorphic function on $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Does there exist a holomorphic function $\varphi(z)$ on $D$ such that $\varphi^2(z) = \psi(z)$? Here $D$ can be a single-connected region or a multi-connected region.

I think for single-connected region, it is true, but I can not prove.

Comment: Simply-connected domain: yes. Otherwise how about $\psi(z)=z$ on $\Bbb C-\{0\}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you, I know it is not true when $D$ is a multi-connected region. but I can not prove it is true when $D$ is a single-connected region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simply connected region $D$, an integral of the form
$$a+\int_{z_0}^z\frac{\psi'(z)}{\psi(z)}\,dz$$
is well-defined, and defines a branch of $\ln\psi(z)$ on $D$.
Can you use that to define a branch of $\sqrt{\psi(z)}$ on $D$?

Comment: Thank you, I know it now, just use $\exp(\frac{\ln\psi(z)}{2})$

Comment: It might be interesting to find an integral method that produces $\sqrt{\varphi}$ directly, without using $\log$ ... Then, for example, it could prove the generalization showing that $\varphi$ has a square-root provided all the zeros of $\varphi$ have even order.